# OAuth Request 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, django, oauth, python-requests, urllib2

Our app uses resources from a third party. The resources we request are supposed to be rendered in an iframe. The way it works based on the third party specs:

The 3rd party app does not provide an access token url, the only url required is the resource url. With that said,

We send a post request after create an OAuth object and signature as follows:

```
import random
import time
from urlparse import parse_qsl, urlparse
from urllib import quote, urlencode
import urllib2
import binascii
import hashlib
import hmac
import webbrowser
import json
import copy
import requests

from django.http import JsonResponse
from myapp.users.models import User

CONSUMER_KEY = 'CONSUMER_KEY'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'CONSUMER_SECRET'

q = lambda x: quote(x, safe="~")
get_timestamp = lambda: int(time.time())
get_nonce = lambda: str(str(random.getrandbits(64)) + str(get_timestamp()))

def get_sign(params, url, http_method, oauth_token_secret=""):
    """returns HMAC-SHA1 sign"""
    params.sort()
    normalized_params = urlencode(params)
    base_string = "&".join((http_method, q(url), q(normalized_params)))
    sig = hmac.new("&".join([CONSUMER_SECRET, oauth_token_secret]), base_string, hashlib.sha1)
    return binascii.b2a_base64(sig.digest())[:-1]

resource_url = 'https://example.com/cat_id/rsc_id'
resource_id = 1001
user = User.objects.get(id=216) # get a user who should have access to the resource

user_resource_data = [
    ('oauth_consumer_key', CONSUMER_KEY),
    ('oauth_nonce', get_nonce()),
    ('oauth_signature_method', "HMAC-SHA1"),
    ('oauth_timestamp', get_timestamp()),
    ('oauth_callback', 'about:blank'),
    ('oauth_version', '1.0'),
    ('resource_link_id', '%s_%s' % (resource_id, user.id)),
    ('user_id', user.id),
    ('lis_person_name_full', user.username),
    ('lis_person_name_family', user.last_name),
    ('lis_person_name_given', user.first_name),
    ('lis_person_contact_email_primary', user.email),
    # these parameters are specific to the LTI Requirements
    ('lti_message_type', 'basic-lti-launch-request'),
    ('lti_version', 'LTI-1p0')
]

signature = get_sign(user_resource_data, resource_url, "POST")
user_resource_data.append(('oauth_signature', signature))

url = "?".join((resource_url, urlencode(user_resource_data)))
resp = requests.post(resource_url, params=user_resource_data)
```

I also tried using the urllib2.urlopen method as follows instead of using Python Requests:

```
resp = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, data=[]))
```

I keep getting a bad request and I am not sure what is going wrong as no error message is returned.

**UPDATE:**
I even tried to just create the OAuth signature and passing all the parameter values to an angular directive that populates the hidden input fields of a form and submits it and supposed to render returned resource in the iframe.

```
<div class="video-container">
   <iframe ng-hide='!loaded'
           allowfullscreen
           frameBorder="0" 
           name="launchFrame"
           id="lesson-frame"
           src="{{ source_url }}"
           scrolling="auto" 
           width="100px";>
    </iframe>
    <div>
      <form method="post" id="launch-form" action="{{ source_url }}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input type="text" name="oauth_consumer_key" value="{{ form_data.oauth_consumer_key }}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="oauth_signature" value="{{ form_data.oauth_signature }}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="oauth_callback" value="auto:blank" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="oauth_signature_method" value="{{ form_data.oauth_signature_method }}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="oauth_nonce" value="{{ form_data.oauth_nonce }}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="user_id" value="{{ form_data.user_id }}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="resource_link_id" value="{{ form_data.resource_link_id }}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="lis_person_contact_email_primary" value="{{ form_data.lis_person_contact_email_primary }}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="lis_person_name_family" value="{{ form_data.lis_person_name_family }}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="lis_person_name_full" value="{{ form_data.lis_person_name_full }}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="lis_person_name_given" value="{{ form_data.lis_person_name_given }}" hidden> 
        <input type="text" name="lti_message_type" value="{{ form_data.lti_message_type }}" hidden> 
        <input type="text" name="lti_version" value="{{ form_data.lti_version }}" hidden> 
        <input type="text" name="oauth_version" value="{{ form_data.oauth_version }}" hidden> 
        <input type="text" name="oauth_timestamp" value="{{ form_data.oauth_timestamp }}" hidden>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The source_url has the url of the resource. All other data is passed through a JsonResponse from the django view that calculates the OAuth Signature. **In the case of submitting the form, I am getting an error that says the OAuth signature is invalid.**

Comment: Why are you sending the user_resource_data in the URL as well as in the POST body?

Comment: The url sent in the 'requests.post' is only the resource_url and does not include the parameters. That is why I am passing the user_resource_data as the params.
As for the urllib2.urlopen method, I am passing the encoded url which includes all the params with no data in the POST body.